# Trying to add formula to excel that will return different results based on price

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm wondering if there is an automatic formula that will return different results based on price. ie < than $10 add 40%, < than $20 (or $11 to $20) add 1.25 and so on instead of me manually doing each cell. Also is there a way to hide formulas other than protecting the sheet. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Basically I have a sheet where I applied 3 different formulas manually. Less than $10 I added 40%, $11-$25 I added 25% and greater than $26, 20%

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you literally even tagged it in your question **sigh...**

`=IF(A1 > 40%, "Do if true", "Else do this")`

Additionally, you can even nest the `IF` functions inside if you need to check multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Depends somewhat on what you want for $10 and $26, but the following might suit:

```
=A1*(1+((A1>0)*8-(A1>9)*3-(A1>26))/20)
```